# Listview : Highlight VBA selected row in blue and not in grey

Tags: vba, excel

In a Userform I have a ListView (**from the reference Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)**) in Excel 2013.

The ListView is configured so :

- FullRowSelect : True
- HideSelection : False
- MultiSelect : True
- View : '3 - lvwReport'

And when I select a row with VBA like :

```
List.ListItems(52).Selected = True
```

The row is highlighted but in **grey**.

How to make it blue highlighted like on click ?

---

I saw on some answers here that it is possible to set :

```
List.Items(52).Focused = True
```

I also tried :

```
List.ListItems(52).EnsureVisible
```

Without success ...

But there is no Items property on my ListView ... (may be an older API ?)

Comment: I don't know if that is causing the problem, but either way you should note that [The FullRowSelect property has no effect unless the View property of the ListView control is set to Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I don't think it's possible: the thing is that, even the selection is being made, that color is set only when focusing an active window, since the code is running at the time it's performing the selection but, the "blue" thingy is within the current active window; since the code is selecting it, it's never going to be active, however, if you really need it, [here is the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.listview_properties.aspx), maybe there is something that I wasn't able to catch while trying

Comment: @Sgdva I think they are several APIs because this mention **items** property and I don't have this property in my excel :(

Comment: @Tom As View values I have only lvwIcon, lvwSmallIcon, lvwList and lvwReport :/

Comment: @Alsatian True, however, some of them are shared, that was the only reference I could find (but I think it's V4 or something)